# Pandas: How to only convert values in a column that are not None?

Tags: python, pandas

pandas `NaT` value is giving me a lot of trouble. As a workaround, I'd like to only convert my `Timestamps()` only if they are not None. That way, I do not end up with `NaT`s in these columns. I have not found a way to apply `df.check_in = pd.to_datetime(pd.check_in)` only to non-`None` values though.

Originally I have Timestamp datatypes, which after performing the above pandas operation, I end up with something like this:

```
457   2015-04-23
458   2015-04-22
459   2015-04-22
460   2015-04-15
461          NaT
462          NaT
463   2014-08-07
464   1993-12-01
465   2007-01-30
```

However, I haven't been able to find a way to convert NaT back to None.

Sorry, one more update: I've tried using `apply()` after everything gets converted with `pd.to_datetime()`. However, I get

```
df.check_in.apply(lambda x: None if pd.isnull(x))
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
```

Comment: Drop the rows that contain `None`?

Comment: What do you want to appear in your column instead of NaT?

Comment: You cannot mix datatypes in one column. You cast a type to the whole column.

Comment: @macaw_9227 I was hoping to keep the `None`s because handling `pd.NaT` is giving me a headache.

Comment: @AlanH , maybe you can share your issues with handling `NaT` , as it is really the equivalent of `None` when you make the column a timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `fillna`

```
df.yourcolumn=pd.to_datetime(df.yourcolumn,errors='coerce').fillna(df.yourcolumn)
```

Toy data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'yourcolumn':['2019-01-01','hehehehe']})
df.yourcolumn=pd.to_datetime(df.yourcolumn,errors='coerce').fillna(df.yourcolumn)
df.yourcolumn
Out[446]: 
0    2019-01-01 00:00:00
1               hehehehe
Name: yourcolumn, dtype: object
```

Comment: pd.NaT is still present though

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def convert_ts(a):
    #do custom conversion respectively
    return to_timestamp(a)


df['converted_dates'] = df.apply(lambda x: convert_ts(x['your_ts']) if pd.isna(x['your_ts']) == False else x['your_ts'])
```

it will apply your conversion function only if it's not nan

[see here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html)